# Error in my pandas script only shows reference to library code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a very typical python script doing some pandas stuff. I've noticed that often when there's an error in my code, the Traceback doesn't contain a reference to a line of my own code, and rather points to a library module, which isn't helpful.

See the following example:

```py
print("Loading stops file...", end=" ")
df = pandas.read_csv("path/to/some.csv")
df['RegistrationCleaned'] = df['Regristation'].str.replace('*','')
print("done.")
```

There's a typo in the column name right of the assignment, which triggers an error. The Traceback is as follows:

```bash
Loading stops file... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\software\python\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3652, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 176, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Regristation'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\software\python\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3654, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Regristation'
```

There's no reference to my code, only to `base.py`. That's not super helpful and I need to manually look for the source of the error. Now this is a trivial example because there's only one line of code which actually does something. So it's not difficult to trace it back. My original script is more complex and the debugging more tedious. My IDE (Pycharm) highlights links to files, which I can use to go directly to the source of the error. But in this case there isn't a link to my own code.

It's not a blocker and I can always add print outs or breakpoints to find the source. But I wonder why the interpreter isn't able to tell that the error was triggered by my own code. I'm using Python 3.11 on Windows 11, don't know if that's relevant.

Any thoughts? Can I change that behaviour so it shows me a line of code in my own script rather than in the library's code? Is this a pandas-specific issue, or linked with the interpreter? Thanks!

Comment: Running from a terminal, e.g. `python test.py` does link to the line in `test.py` in call stack.